# Text on DrawString not centering vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, graphics, gdi+, centering

This text won't center on the control.
After searching for a bit I have found nothing that has helped me.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(Me.ForeColor.R, Me.ForeColor.G, Me.ForeColor.B)), New PointF(Me.Size.Width / 2, Me.Size.Height / 2))
```

Comment: Draw in a rectangle instead (`Me.ClientRectangle`) and use the [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_StringFormat__ctor) to center the string in the drawing rectangle.

Comment: Can you give more context to the question? What kind of Control is this? Does the `e.Graphics` object come from the Control's `PaintEventArgs`? As @JQSOFT mentioned, you need to specify an area, not a Point, to let the Graphics method  determine the string layout correctly. You may have better results using `TextRenderer.DrawText()` in may situations.